# Cordova iOS application preferences plugin caching issue

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using this handy Cordova plugin to set application settings from the homepage of my Cordova iOS hybrid app:

https://github.com/escio/cordova-ios-application-preferences

I have a local hybrid app and from the index.html homepage, and I set an application preference when a user clicks a button, using this plugin.

On success of setting the application preference, I have confirmed via logging that the setting is correctly set. At that point, I call a JS function that looks at the application preferences. What's weird is that although the log indicates that I've set the preference correctly, my JS function is still using/referring to the default value for that preference. If I exit the app and restart it immediately, it's clearly working with the newer application preference but on that initial flow, the app appears to be using a cached version of the application preference.

Any ideas here? How can I get Cordova to use the current application preference?

Answer (score 1):

To close the loop on this, I discovered that although the plugin was setting the value, the hybrid app had a bunch of native code running and the settings values were grabbed by the app at initialization. So in addition to setting the new value in the Application Preferences, I had to add a small method call into the plugin, in objective-c, to set the new value on the native side of the application memory/state.